# Postgresql ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint << bigint

Tags: postgresql, comparison, comparison-operators, bigint

My algorithm was working fine but with a new big database, my integers variable exceed the max limit size. (I use the powerset algorithm : https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060924054759.GA71934%40winnie.fuhr.org)

So I've decided to change all of my integer to bigint, but now I have a problem on the comparison operator... I don't know how to manage it :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION powerset(a anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    retval  a%TYPE;
    alower  bigint := array_lower(a, 1);
    aupper  bigint := array_upper(a, 1);
    j       bigint;
    k       bigint;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. COALESCE((CAST(1 AS BIGINT) << (aupper - alower + 1)) - 1, 0) LOOP
        retval := '{}';
        j := alower;
        k := i;

        WHILE k > CAST(0 AS BIGINT) LOOP
            IF k & CAST(1 AS BIGINT) = CAST(1 AS BIGINT) THEN
                retval := array_append(retval, a[j]);
            END IF;

            j := j + CAST(1 AS BIGINT);
            k := k >> CAST(1 AS BIGINT);
        END LOOP;

        RETURN NEXT retval;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION powerset(anyarray)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I've got the error on line :

```
FOR i IN 1 .. COALESCE((CAST(1 AS BIGINT) << (aupper - alower + 1)) - 1, 0) LOOP
```

Error 42883
Postgresql ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint << bigint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the right operand of bitwise shift operators is `integer.` Unfortunately, this was not mentioned in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html) (The documentation was corrected [in Postgres 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-math.html))

You should cast the right operand of shift operators to `integer:`

```
-- instead of 
-- COALESCE((CAST(1 AS BIGINT) << (aupper - alower + 1)) - 1, 0)
-- use
select COALESCE(1 << (aupper - alower + 1)::int- 1, 0)::bigint

-- instead of
-- k := k >> CAST(1 AS BIGINT);
--- use
k := k >> 1;
-- etc
```

You can check possible types of operands by querying the system catalog [`pg_operator`,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-operator.html) e.g.:

```
select oprname, oprleft::regtype, oprright::regtype
from pg_operator
where oprname = '<<'
and oprcode::text like '%shl%' -- shift left functions

 oprname | oprleft  | oprright 
---------+----------+----------
 <<      | smallint | integer
 <<      | integer  | integer
 <<      | bigint   | integer
(3 rows)
```

The above result shows that left operand of the operator `<<` (bitwise shift left) can be `smallint,` `integer` or `bigint` and right operand must be `integer.`

Comment: Thanks ! What is the difference between int2shl, int4shl, int8shl  so ?

So I have to do it for all of my algorithm ? Each comparison operator has to been changed in function ?